# Tableview not showing any of the arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a in app setting tableview, which requires different sections with different content. i first tried all the code outside (!cell), but that resulted in duplicate of the content on scroll, i've then found thread where it said i needed to put inside (!cell), but now it does not show any content. What am i doing wrong?

## CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.953 green:0.953 blue:0.965 alpha:1] ;
    self.emailTextField.delegate = self;
    
    
    self.cellName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 12, 42, 20)];
    self.cellName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.137 green:0.145 blue:0.157 alpha:1];
    self.cellName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.cellName];
    
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        
        
        self.cellName.text = [notArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            self.acceptanceSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(251, 6, 31, 51)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.acceptanceSwitch];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            self.messageSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(251, 6, 31, 51)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.messageSwitch];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            self.likeSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(251, 6, 31, 51)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.likeSwitch];
        }
    } else if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        
        self.cellName.text = [accountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            self.nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 7, 190, 30)];
            self.nameTextField.enabled = NO;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.nameTextField];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            self.emailTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 7, 190, 30)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.emailTextField];
            [self.emailTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
            [self.emailTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            self.genderSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(251, 6, 31, 51)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.genderSwitch];
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
}



if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    self.cellName.text = [accountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    

    
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    

    self.cellName.text = [notArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    

    
    
    
    
} else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    

    self.cellName.text = [policyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    
} else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
    

    self.cellName.text = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.cellName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    
}



return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1. create a subclass of UITableViewCell with public properties (label, textfield). If you have different requirement for cells in different sections, maybe you should have different cell subclasses.
2. register these cell classes with the tableview in your view did load. e.g.

   [self.tableView registerClass:[MySectionOneTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:MySectionOneIdentifier];
   [self.tableView registerClass:[MySectionTwoTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:MySectionTwoIdentifier];
3. in the method below, just dequeue the cell after making a check for the section and set the properties.

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell* cell;
     if (indexPath.section == 0){
         cell = (MySectionOneTableViewCell*)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MySectionOneIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath;
         cell.textLabel = @"foo";
     }
     return cell;
     }
4. implement method, prepare for reuse  in your custom uitableviewcell classes where you initialize all your labels and text fields. This method prepares the views of the cell for reuse. 
   e.g.

   - (void)prepareForReuse {
     self.textLabel.text = @""; 
     }

Answer (score -1):

As mentionned @rmaddy, you shouldn't mention the cell generation in your (!cell). The "code illustration" is the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // This part wasn't included in any specific if/else condition dealing with cell properties (like section or row), not either being modified during the cell generation
    self.emailTextField.delegate = self;
    self.cellName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 12, 42, 20)];
    self.cellName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.137 green:0.145 blue:0.157 alpha:1];
    self.cellName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    // This part ensure you will initiate each cell with the correct identifier
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.953 green:0.953 blue:0.965 alpha:1] ;
    }

    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.cellName];

    // You should check your code and commute the common condition together
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        self.cellName.text = [accountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Be aware that your first section will contain only 3 rows
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            self.nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 7, 190, 30)];
            self.nameTextField.enabled = NO;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.nameTextField];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            self.emailTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 7, 190, 30)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.emailTextField];
            [self.emailTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
            [self.emailTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            self.genderSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(251, 6, 31, 51)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.genderSwitch];
        }
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        self.cellName.text = [notArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Be aware that your second section will contain only 3 rows
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            self.acceptanceSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(251, 6, 31, 51)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.acceptanceSwitch];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            self.messageSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(251, 6, 31, 51)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.messageSwitch];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            self.likeSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(251, 6, 31, 51)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.likeSwitch];
        }
    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        // Here you are not adding any specific content to your section 2
        self.cellName.text = [policyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    } else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        // The same, your fourth section won't content any specific content
        // You should add something like [cell addSubview:MyCustomView]
        self.cellName.text = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.cellName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    }

    return cell;
}
```

As I mentioned in my comments, if your local properties (`cellName`, `nameTextField`, `genderSwitch`, etc...) are well implemented, you will have only 6 row in all your table (3 in the first section and 3 in the second. Your third and fourth section will be empty since you didn't mention any subview within them.

Finally, since your code contained many confusion for me, it is possible I made some mistake in my rewriting, so feel free to correct me in this case.

Hopping it will help you in your work.

Comment: This results in the cellname label is shown quickly and then dissapearing when scrolling up.